# Partion table mmcblk0boot0 device

Tags: partition, gpt

I created two GPT partitions in /dev/mmcblk0boot0 device. Now I want to format one of them. But I don't have any idea how to access to a single partition. When I created partitions on "normal" device like sda, the partitions would be available as sda0, sda1 etc.

How can I access a single partition?

Answer (score 3):

`mmcblk0boot` is a (special) partition itself, so you should not create partitions there. Instead, create partitions on `/dev/mmcblk0`. These partitions should show up as `/dev/mmcblk0p1`, `/dev/mmblk0p2`, etc.

Comment: I'm aware this is special eMMC boot partition but in our project we make use of it. Anyway I found a solution. It is possible to map the partitions inside mmcblk0boot using kpartx.